# How do I fetch data from my back-end (localhost) that's being sent through Fetch API? (PHP, Fetch, React Native, POST request)

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, fetch

```
fetch("http://10.0.2.2:80/NewAdmin/scripts/main/transactions", {
        method:'post',
        headers:{
           "Accept":"application/json", 
           "Content-type":"application/json" 
        },
        // (var) payload looks like this {Header: "Sending", . . .} 
        body:JSON.stringify(payload)
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(resp => console.log(resp))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**My PHP code**

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $json;
if($json["Header"] == "Sending"){
    echo json_encode('!WTF');
}else{
    echo json_encode('WTF!'); 
}
?>
```

It returns 'WTF!'—no pun intended. What am I missing?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Log the value of `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Log the value of `$Jjson`.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: It returns null

Comment: I figured it out I didn't include http://10.0.2.2:80/NewAdmin/scripts/main/transactions/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, it should return 'action test' OR Error,
JS Code:

```
fetch(ConfigApp.URL + 'transactions.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      action: 'action test',
      p: 'addSession',
    }),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      console.warn(responseJson)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.warn(Strings.no_result + error.message);
});
```

PHP transactionsv.php:

```
<?php

 
//Make sure that it is a POST request.
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
}
//Make sure that the content type of the POST request has been set to application/json
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
}
//Receive the RAW post data.
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
//Attempt to decode the i ncoming RAW post data from JSON.
$decoded = json_decode($content, true);

if(!is_array($decoded)){
    $json_string = json_encode(false);
    print ($json_string);
    die();
}elseif(!isset($decoded["p"])){
    $decoded = $decoded[0];
}

switch ($decoded["p"]) {
    case 'addSession':
            print (json_encode($decoded['action']));
    break;
    default:
        $json_string = json_encode(false);
        print ($json_string);
    break;

}
```

Comment: I figured it out I didn't include `http://10.0.2.2:80/NewAdmin/scripts/main/transactions/index.php`